# Assert workaround in JUnit

Tags: java, junit

I've seen today a non standard way of writing unit tests with JUnit,

instead of using the framework checks

```
Assert.assertTrue("Unexpected response encoding", text.length() >= 1);
```

a generic exception is thrown

```
if (text.length() < 1) {
    throw new Exception("Unexpected response encoding");
}
```

I want to to convince the author to adopt the first style. Beside reason like verbosity, clarity of intent do you know what else can differ in these approaches?

Comment: Do you *need* anything more than the first two, and convention?

Comment: If they really must use that format they could at least use Assert.fail() instead of throwing an exception.

Comment: @Brian Agnew edited the question, it was a mistake. The question is about the style assuming the condition is the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Their treatment in report is different in two ways:

1. As mentioned by @Matt, one is failure while other is error.
2. Imagene `Assert.assertEquals`, when failed, it reports both `expected` and `found` values in the report along with the message.

Answer (score 3):

JUnit reports will show the first style as a "failure" whereas the second is shown as an "error" since an uncaught exception is thrown.

It depends on if you care about this type of labeling and is completely subjective, but personally I would prefer to see this as a "failure".

Comment: That's a very good point. You're distinguishing between tested and untested errors in the code

Comment: Seems as though in JUnit 4, the framework itself doesn't distinguish between failures and errors (see org.junit.runner.notification.Failure). Custom runners, such as the one provided by Eclipse, might still call an uncaught `AssertionError` a failure and other uncaught exceptions errors.

Comment: @pholser, that's a fair point. I was mostly thinking of runners in Eclipse and IntelliJ, and what the maven surefire plugin reports (each separates failures from errors).

Answer (score 0):

If your primary goal is to convince someone to use the first approach over the second and you need more ammo (I agree with Jon Skeet's comment that you shouldn't need more ammo.) then use some code coverage tool over your test code.

Good developers will effortlessly get 100% coverage on their unit tests.  Bad developers will not get 100% coverage without going into the `if` condition.  Either way you can nag the bad developer.  Why isn't your coverage 100%? or why do you have failing unit tests?

It s not fair, but it will motivate the desired behavior.